# AppleScript open location command not working with variable

Tags: bash, macos, applescript

The following script...

```
open location "smb://fileserver02.domain1.com.au/department"
```

works as expected, it connects to the drive and prompts the user to enter a username and password.

However, when I try to build the domain and username into the command and then connect, the open location command does not work, no error it just simply does nothing.

```
set userName to do shell script "whoami"
set p to "\"smb:DOMAIN2\\" & userName & "@fileserver02.domain1.com.au/department\"" as string
open location p
```

I've confirmed that the string is being built correctly into the p variable and it works if I type the command out like so...

```
open location "smb:DOMAIN2\\RoryP@fileserver02.domain1.com.au/department"
```

It just does not work when it's contained in a variable...

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I thought of a better way to do this with a one liner.
 
do shell script "open 'smb://DOMAIN02\\$(whoami)@fileserver02.domain1.com.au/department'"

But it only works sometimes... I copied the exact script file to another computer and ran it but it does not resolve $(whoami), it opens a credential prompt with the username filled in as "DOMAIN02\$(whoami)"
On my device (running the exact same macOS version) it resolves $(whoami) and fills the username field as expected and connects to the drive, very weird. 

Why would it resolve the variable on one device but not the other?

Answer (score 0):

Don't put escaped quotes at both ends of your variable.

```
set userName to do shell script "whoami"
set p to ("smb:DOMAIN2//" & userName & "@fileserver02.domain1.com.au/department") as string
open location p
```

Comment: Changed \\ to //

Comment: I've removed the escaped quotes but am finding almost the same result, the script now changes the active window to Finder however it does not connect to the drive.

Also I a need a single backslash, hence the double backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the literal double quotes at the beginning and the end of the string. As the current short username cannot contain special characters you don't need to escape the entire string.

On the other hand to get two backslashes you have to escape both.

```
set userName to do shell script "whoami"
set p to "smb:DOMAIN2\\\\" & userName & "@fileserver02.domain1.com.au/department"
open location p
```

Comment: Aren’t URLs supposed to contain regular slashes ?

Comment: I'm escaping 1 backslash, so hence the 2 slashes. 
the resulting p value should be
"smb:DOMAIN2\RoryP@fileserver02.domain1.com.au/department"

Comment: Specifying a domain in this format is a backslash, 
e.g thedomain\theusername@theserver.theotherdomain.com.au

In my case we have multiple domains with trust across them however due to an obscure quirk in our firewall settings only 1 search domain can be entered meaning we have to specify the other domains in various locations

Comment: Then remove two backslashes.

Comment: Yeah, tried that but had no luck. It switches to Finder as the active window now but does not connect to the drive.